# iOS UIButton in programmatically instantiated subview not firing

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uibutton

I have a Nib in my storyboard which is not connected to anything but I'm instantiating it as a subview thusly:

```
-(void)LoadCameraOverlayView
{
    CameraOverlayViewController *cameraVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CameraOverlayNib"];
    cameraVC.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:cameraVC.view];
}
```

The UIViewController has a camera with feedback which is working fine and a button which (when I segue to the view controller also works fine.)

The button is linked to a Touch Down event and Touch Up Inside event.

When I click the button I can see it is changing visually from its default state to its focused or highlighted state however none of the code seems to be executing. If I put an NSLog in the ViewDidLoad I can see that in the console but not for the linked method. However if I segue to the view it does work.

What's going on?

I looked at other solutions but I don't think it could be that there is a view in the way or that the CGRect isn't calibrated correctly or anything since I can see the visual change when clicking the button.

Comment: Where do you add the selector for the button touchDown and touchUp in CameraOverlayViewController? Was in done in interface builder or programmatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code violates Rule One of how to use view controllers:

```
CameraOverlayViewController *cameraVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CameraOverlayNib"];
[self.view addSubview:cameraVC.view];
```

You cannot simply instantiate a view controller and then add its view manually to the view hierarchy like that. There are very strict rules about this; there is an elaborate "dance" that you must do in order to add a view controller's view to your interface manually, and you are not doing the dance.

The result is that your `cameraVC` comes into existence, is given no place in the view controller hierarchy, and vanishes in a puff of smoke. There is thus no object for your button to talk to, and so when the button is tapped, nothing happens.

My suggestion would be: use a *.xib* file, not a storyboard scene, for this view; and after you have loaded it and put it into the interface, use code to configure the button so that it talks to `self`, your *current* view controller.

Comment: thank you for your reply, I'll look into it. Do you know any resources that could point me in the right direction with how to learn about better coding practice with regards to this? Would you possibly also be able to explain to me how to load a xib into the interface? At the end are you implying I use the storyboard view controller as a delegate?

Comment: "Would you possibly also be able to explain to me how to load a xib into the interface?" Certainly; my online book explains it to you: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch07.html#_nib_loading_and_file_8217_s_owner

Comment: And here is an actual downloadable example where I do just what I'm suggesting you do (in my `viewDidLoad`): I load a view from a nib, put it into the interface, and configure its button in code: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/iOS7bookExamples/bk2ch10p524keyboardAccessory/ch21p808keyboardAccessory/ViewController.m

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciate this